# Rearrange same types of data values in same columns in R

Tags: r

I have my data like this:

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("16S", "M"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("M", "T1", "T2", 
"T3", "T4"), class = "factor"), X3 = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "T1", 
"T2", "T3", "T4"), class = "factor"), X4 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", 
"S1", "S2", "S3"), class = "factor"), X5 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("16S", "S1", "S2", "S3"
), class = "factor")), row.names = 92:100, class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to put all values starting with M in one column, T in another; values starting with S in one column and ending in S in another column and so forth (keeping the row number as is). How can I do this in R?

## expected result:

```
X1 X2 X3 X4  X5
92  16S  M T4 R4  S1
93  16S  M T4 R4  S2
94  16S  M T4 R4  S2
95  16S  M T4 R4  S3
96  16S  M T4 R4  S3
97  16S  M T1 R1  S1 
98  16S  M T1 R1  S1 
99  16S  M T1 R1  S2 
100 16S  M T1 R1  S2
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  I can see a lot of edge cases when there corresponding letter is not found in a particular row

Comment: @akrun please see the updated question

Comment: So you want to do string-marching on the labels of a factor. Do you want NA, "" or empty-list in the unused columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be `sort` on row wise

```
df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, sort))
df
#     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#92  16S  M R4 S1 T4
#93  16S  M R4 S2 T4
#94  16S  M R4 S2 T4
#95  16S  M R4 S3 T4
#96  16S  M R4 S3 T4
#97  16S  M R1 S1 T1
#98  16S  M R1 S1 T1
#99  16S  M R1 S2 T1
#100 16S  M R1 S2 T1
```

Comment: Thank you. Works for me.